# Matlab - Add a specific tick on a colorbar

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm representing a surface using "surf" function, with a colorbar. I would like to keep the default ticks of the colorbar, but add a custom tick on this colorbar, at a specific value (that I could make red to distinguish it from other ticks for example). Any idea on how to add a custom tick like that with keeping existing ticks on the colorbar ?

Thanks

Comment: To add a tick you can use for example: `h = colorbar; h.Ticks = sort([h.Ticks .75]);` Changing the color would be difficult, I think

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Luis, I tagged on an annotation to get it over the line

Comment: @Wolfie Good idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Luis mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69724582/matlab-add-a-specific-tick-on-a-colorbar#comment123247468_69724582) in the comments, you can add an additional tick mark like so

```
h = colorbar; 
newTick = 0.75;
h.Ticks = sort([h.Ticks newTick]);
```

If you want to add a line to the bar, the easiest thing (I think) is to use an `annotation` which is positioned relative to the figure (the same as the `colorbar`), so we can overlay it

```
pos = h.Position;
r = (newTick - min(h.Ticks))/(max(h.Ticks)-min(h.Ticks));
annotation( 'line', pos(1)+[0, pos(3)], [1, 1]*(pos(2)+pos(4)*r), ...
            'color', [1,0,0], 'linewidth', 2 );
```

I'm setting the `x` position of the annotation to match the left and right sides of the colorbar, and the `y` position to match the bottom plus the relative % of the height according to the tick value.

Result:

[image: plot]

Similarly, you could use `annotatation` exclusively to just get a red label, it's a little more convoluted to get everything lined up correctly, you have to make sure the text box is wide enough to be on a single line and vertically aligned to the middle to get the position right:

```
h = colorbar; 
newTick = 0.75;
pos = h.Position;
r = (newTick - min(h.Ticks))/(max(h.Ticks)-min(h.Ticks));
h = 0.2;
annotation( 'textbox', [pos(1)+pos(3)/2, (pos(2)+pos(4)*r)-(h/2), pos(3)*2, h], ...
    'color', [1,0,0], 'string', ['- ' num2str(newTick)], 'linestyle', 'none', ...
    'VerticalAlignment', 'middle' );
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: Thanks a lot for those answers, I was not expecting such complete answers as quickly as that ^^"

I tried your code above, I have a couple of questions. 

When I do the code in your 1st block, only the newTick appear, not the others. But it should appear? probably due to the fact that my figure is in a subplot maybe ?

And I can't position like you did the annotation, maybe I'm missing something, is there supposed to be code where you put the "..." before 'color' ? Sorry I'm a beginner ^^"

Comment: What's the value of `h.Ticks` before overwriting it (straight after `h = colorbar`)? This should contain the default tick mark values, the line containing `sort` combines the `newTick` into these. I don't think it should matter that you've got a subplot, but have you tried running the above code exactly as it is, i.e run `clear; close all` and just run my code, does it work? It's not clear why you "can't position" it like I did, why not? Have you tried looking at the colorbar's `h.Position` to see what's going on?

Comment: `...` is just [line continuation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/continue-long-statements-on-multiple-lines.html) for readability

Comment: Yeah with your code it works. The problem is that my value of h.Ticks don't match the ticks that I actually see on my plot. On my plot my colorbar goes from 35 to 44. The value of h.Ticks is a vector from 0 to 35 idk why. So when I add and sort my tick (at 37), on the final plot I only see 35 and 37, no other ticks. So the problem comes from getting the value of h.Ticks on my side.

Thanks a lot for your answer, that helped me a lot !

Comment: And for the position, the red line appear stuck at the top of my colorbar didn't understand why yet. h.Position gives me  [0.4397    0.5838    0.0111    0.3412].